# Dialogflow: Regex checkbox missing from options?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I wanted to add an entity and test it using RegEx.
I'm looking at examples, and everyone has the ability to check the RegEx box, but that's missing on my interface.

Why is that?

Here's my screen:
[image: missing regex box]

Comment: Hi OP, did you have any actions prior going to "Create Entity" option? If yes, an you provide exact step-by-step scenario before you clicked the  "Create Entity". Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I just opened a new tab, opened dialogflow, clicked on entities, then new entity, then regex was there. Weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, logging out of the Dialogflow and logging in again fixed the problem for me.